# How to use JAI library in windows xp

Tags: java

I have Downloaded the JAI library jar file from the net. Now, I'm unable to install and make use of that file in my programs. I have even tried setting classpath, but it is not working. What to do now?

I'm repeatedly getting this error : 
  error: package javax.media.jai does not exist

Comment: You've checked the instructions here, right? http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html#Windows

Comment: yeah, but its still not working. can u provide me the link to download the files required for this purpose?